# New Window Opens Under Current

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I have a window that I'm building in code, and showing:

```
Window wndViewer = new Window();
wndViewer.Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31));
wndViewer.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
wndViewer.Width = 1024;
wndViewer.Height = 768;

Grid grd = new Grid();

wndViewer.Title = "<Removed>";

Viewer vw = new Viewer(); // This is a UserControl
vw.StudyDate = ((StudyItem)sender).StudyDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
vw.PatientName = ((StudyItem)sender).PatientName;
vw.PatientId = ((StudyItem)sender).OwnerName;

vw.Margin = new Thickness(3, 30, 3, 3);
vw.StudyInstance = ((StudyItem)sender).ItemStudy;
grd.Children.Add(vw);

wndViewer.Content = grd;

refreshTimer.Stop();

wndViewer.Tag = vw.StudyInstance;

wndList.Add(wndViewer); // List<Window> of all the windows opened this way.

DependencyObject dpParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(this);

while (dpParent != null && dpParent.GetType() != typeof(Window))
{
    dpParent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(dpParent);
}

wndViewer.Owner = (Window)dpParent;

wndViewer.ShowActivated = true;

wndViewer.Show();
```

The problem is that I need this window to be displayed on top of the current window, and it always comes up under the current window. I've tried several solutions:

```
wndViewer.BringIntoView();
```

Importing and calling:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SetForegroundWindow(int hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
```

So, I'm sure I'm overlooking something here. Thanks for any help!

~md5sum~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the `TopMost` property of the window?

You can find more information on the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost.aspx)

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether a window appears in the topmost z-order. This is a dependency property.

As you point out in your comment, this will make the window always the top most. It would also be "hackish" to reset the flag after the window has been shown.

**EDIT**

I've just seen in your code that you're setting the `Owner` property of the window to be:

```
wndViewer.Owner = (Window)dpParent;
```

I've used this which seems to "just work":

```
var about = new AboutBox();
about.Owner = this;
about.Initialise();
about.Show();
```

Now in this case `AboutBox` is derived from `Window` rather than `UserControl`, so there may be something here, but is there any reason you need to set `Owner` to something other than `this`?

Comment: That seems to have done the trick... However, it's a bit "hackish", since now the dynamic windows have to be moved off the main window in order to get back to the main window. It will definitely work for now though!

Comment: "this" in this case isn't a window, but rather a UserControl, so I'm getting the logical parent window and using that, since the owner property ONLY accepts a window. Also, the Window class doesn't have a publicly accessible Initialise method, so that must be specific to the AboutBox.

Comment: And (hackish or not) resetting the flag in the vw.Loaded event  handler has the exact effect I'm needing here. The window comes up in front, but doesn't force itself to the front all the time.

Comment: @md5sum - thanks for the explanation on your setting of `Owner`.